# DDD entity with complex creation process

Tags: domain-driven-design

How entities with complex creation process should be created in DDD?  Example:

```
Entity
 - Property 1
 - Property 2: value depends on what was provided in Property 1
 - Property 3: value depends on what was provided in Property 1
 - Property 4: value depends on what was provided in Property 1, 2 and 3
```

I have two ideas but both looks terrible:

- Create entity with invalid state
- Move creation process to service

We are using REST API so in first scenario we will have to persist entity with invalid state and in second scenario we move logic outside of the entity.

Comment: what do you mean by invalid state?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to solve this problem.

You can make a Builder that has the logic for the dependencies between properties and raise Exceptions, return errors or has a mechanism to tell the *client* which are the next valid steps.

If you are using an object orienterd language, the builder can also return different concrete classes based on the combination of these properties.

Here's a very simplified example. We will store a configuration for EventNotifications that can either listen on some Endpoint (IP, port) or poll.

```
enum Mode { None, Poll, ListenOnEndpoint }

public class EventListenerNotification {

    public Mode Mode { get; set; }
    public Interval PollInterval { get; set; }
    public Endpoint Endpoint { get; set; }
}

public class Builder {

    private Mode mMode = Mode.None;
    private Interenal mInterval;
    private Endpoint mEndpoint;

    public Builder WithMode(Mode mode) {
        this.mMode = mode;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder WithInterval(Interval interval) { 

        VerifyModeIsSet();
        verifyModeIsPoll();

        this.mInterval = interval;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder WithEndpoint(Endpoint endpoint) { 

        VerifyModeIsSet();
        verifyModeIsListenOnEndpoint();

        this.mInterval = interval;
        return this;
    }

    public EventListenerNotification Build() {

        VerifyState();

        var entity = new EventListenerNotification();

        entity.Mode = this.mMode;
        entity.Interval = this.mInterval;
        entity.Endpoint = this.mEndpoint;

        return entity;
    }

    private void VerifyModeIsSet() {

        if(this.mMode == Mode.None) {
            throw new InvalidModeException("Set mode first");
        }
    }

    private void VerifyModeIsPoll() {

        if(this.mMode != Mode.Poll) {
            throw new InvalidModeException("Mode should be poll");
        }
    }

    private void VerifyModeIsListenForEvents() {

        if(this.mMode != Mode.ListenForEvents) {
            throw new InvalidModeException("Mode should be ListenForEvents");
        }
    }

    private void VerifyState() {

        // validate properties based on Mode
        if(this.mMode == Mode.Poll) {
            // validate interval
        }

        if(this.mMode == Mode.ListenForEvents) {
            // validate Endpoint
        }
    }
}

enum BuildStatus { NotStarted, InProgress, Errored, Finished }


public class BuilderWithStatus {

    private readonly List<Error> mErrors = new List<Error>();

    public BuildStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Error> Errors { get { return mErrors; } }

    public BuilderWithStatus WithInterval(Interval inerval) {

        if(this.mMode != Mode.Poll) {
            this.mErrors.add(new Error("Mode should be poll");
            this.Status = BuildStatus.Errored;
        }
        else {
            this.mInterval = interval;
        }

        return this;
    }

    // rest is same as above, but instead of throwing errors you can record the error
    // and set a status
}
```

Here are some resources with more information and other machisms that you can use:

https://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html

https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Notification.html

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContextualValidation.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at chapter 6 of the Evans book, which specifically talks about the life cycle of entities in the domain model

Creation is usually handled with a *factory*, which is to say a function that accepts data as input and returns a reference to an entity.

> in second scenario we move logic outside of the entity.

The simplest answer is for the "factory" to be some method associate with the entity's class - ie, the constructor, or some other static method that is still part of the definition of the entity in the domain model.

> But problem is that creation of the entity requires several steps.

OK, so what you have is a protocol, which is to say a state machine, where you collect information from the outside world, and eventually emit a new entity.

The instance of the state machine, with the data that it has collected, is *also an entity*.

For example, creating an actionable order might require a list of items, and shipping addresses, and billing information.  But we don't necessarily need to collect all of that information at the same time - we can get a little bit now, and remember it, and then later when we have all of the information, we emit the submitted order.

It may take some care with the domain language to distinguish the tracking entity from the finished entity (which itself is probably an input to another state machine....)

Comment: Yes I understand that we can use factory if we need additional logic when entity is created. But problem is that creation of the entity requires several steps. For example when user is creating Entity and he decide that ```Property 1 = ‘X’``` then for ```Property 2``` he have to choose from list ```[1,2,3]``` and in case ```Property 1 = ‘Y’``` list is ```[2,4,6]```. To make it more complicated available list values are links to other aggregate roots. Maybe this is because of bad design of Entity that was forced by legacy system and can be solved with anti-corruption layer.